# How to print out mySQL database into a div table?

Tags: php, html

Grades table is this:

```
username  assignment  weight  mark
a         a1          10%     50%
b         a1          10%     60%
```

How would I print this out using php/html?

```
           <div class="a">
                <div class="divTableHeading">
                    <div class="divTableRow">
                        <div class="divTableHead">Username</div>
                        <div class="divTableHead">assignment</div>
                        <div class="divTableHead">weight</div>
                        <div class="divTableHead">mark</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="divTableBody">

            <?php
                include("config.php");
                $sql = "SELECT username, assignment, weight, mark FROM grades";
                $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {



            ?>


                    <div class="divTableRow">
                        <div class="divTableCell">$row['username']</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell">$row['assignment']</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell">$row['weight']</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell">$row['mark']</div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
```

$db is the connected database that is from config.php. How would I keep looping through and output the grades table?

accidental edit

Comment: Is that the whole code?

Comment: without the html / body tags

Comment: You're missing the `}` for the `while` loop.

Comment: Yeah, I'm unsure where to put it because it's part of the <?php but i also need to have the html inside it

Comment: After the HTML you want to be outputted in your loop (I'm assuming above the last 2 `</div>`s), just do `<?php } ?>`.

Comment: After `<div class="divTableCell">$row['mark']</div>
                    </div>` - add a `<?php } ?>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them

Comment: dont forget the `echo` though

Comment: @Ghost There's a `?>`

Comment: @Mike what i mean is there is a missing echo `<?php echo $row['username']; ?>`, plus like other comments above saying the missing closing curly brace `}`

Comment: @Ghost Ah, yeah you're right. I thought you meant to output the whole block of HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing to echo your record values.

From just `$row['username']` changed to `<?php echo $row['username']; ?>`

And you missed `}` to close your while loop. Closed it as well with - `<?php } ?>`

**Updated code:**

```
 <div class="divTable blueTable">
    <div class="divTableHeading">
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableHead">Username</div>
            <div class="divTableHead">assignment</div>
            <div class="divTableHead">weight</div>
            <div class="divTableHead">mark</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableBody">

<?php
    include("config.php");
    $sql = "SELECT username, assignment, weight, mark FROM grades";
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableCell"><?php echo $row['username']; ?></div>
            <div class="divTableCell"><?php echo $row['assignment']; ?>/div>
            <div class="divTableCell"><?php echo $row['weight']; ?></div>
            <div class="divTableCell"><?php echo $row['mark']; ?></div>
        </div>

<?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to output your values

```
<?php echo $row['username']; ?>
```